# $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ is invertible implies $D$ is locally principal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

With words added for context, 14.2.G of Ravil Vakil's notes asks

Suppose $X$ is an integral, normal and Noetherian scheme, and $D$ a Weil divisor. Let $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ be the quasicoherent sheaf defined by 
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X(D)) :=\{t\in K(X)^{\times}: {\rm div}|_U t + D|_U\geq 0\}\cup \{0\}\}.
\end{align*} 
Suppose in addition that $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ is invertible.

(a) Let $s$ be the rational section of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ corresponding to the function $1\in K(X)$ in the defintion above. Show that ${\rm div}(s)=D$.

(To clarify what $s$ is, we can see that 1 is a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ away from the support of $D$. If referring to it as "1" is confusing, Vakil uses the notation $\sigma(1)$, where $\sigma$ takes $f\in K(X)$ and outputs a rational section. More generally, if $f\in K(X)$, then $\sigma(f)$ is a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ away from the poles of $f$ and the support of $D$. We can compute the divisor of $\sigma(f)$ by taking local trivializations.)

(b) Show that $D$ is locally principal.

I think I see how (a) and (b) are equivalent, and I have tried to do (b) directly by taking an open set $U$ over which $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ is trivial, and fixing an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X|_U\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(D)|_U$.

Then, we can let $s$ be the image of 1, and try to get a contradiction if ${\rm div}(s)|_U>-D|_U$ by finding a section that is not a multiple of $s$. For example, if given an integral, noetherian, and normal ring $A$, a height 1 prime is never contained in the union of the remaining height 1 primes, I think this approach can work.

However, I think I am just missing something obvious. How do we prove (a) directly, as the exercise intends? (This is not homework, and I'm mainly hoping for a good way to understand why (b) is true.)

Comment: Do you know how to associate to Weil divisor a Cartier divisor?

Comment: Not yet, no. I will soon, but it shouldn't logically depend on it to see why D should be locally principal.

Comment: Also, from flipping open Hartshorne, I'm guessing to get a Cartier divisor, I'd want to find local functions (f,U) such that the divisors of the functions agree with D. This seems to require that D is locally principal.

Comment: Something is off with (a). $1 \in K(U)$ need not be a section of $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X(D))$ if $D$ is not effective.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is supposed to be a rational section. I'll change it.

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding" in (a)? Certainly not that $s = 1$.

Comment: Okay, I'll clarify this in the problem by trying to define what $s$ is. (It is a separate exercise.)

Comment: $1$ is certainly a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ away from the support of $D$. But then it seems as if you are saying that $\mathrm{div}(1) = D$ which is not always true.

Comment: I think I'm saying exactly this. Could you tell me what's wrong?

If we assume D is locally principal, then over a small enough open U, there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X|_U\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(D)|_U$ that sends $t$ to $tg$, where ${\rm div}_{X}(g)|_U= -D|_U$. In particular, $g^{-1}$ goes to $1$, which means ${\rm div}_{\mathcal{O}_X(D)}(\sigma(1))|_U = D|_U$. Repeating this for an open cover shows ${\rm div}_{\mathcal{O}_X(D)}(\sigma(1))=D$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the definition of $\mathrm{div}$ (which is with respect to an invertible sheaf). Everything is fine.

Comment: Dear Dtseng, Just a remark: the equivalence between $D$ being locally principal and $\mathcal O_X(D)$ being invertible is so basic, fundamental, and intuitive (once you've had some experience with these sorts of things) that it's going to be hard to separate out the arguments into any fixed logical sequence.  So don't be surprised if your arguments follow a different order to the one suggested by the lay out of the exercise;  all these statements are so closely bound together that it's hard to prove one without proving all of them at once (so the precise ordering is a little random).  Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are approaching the exercise in the expected way. Forget that (b) even exists. Then how would you approach (a)? To even say what $\mathrm{div}(s)$ means, you need to look at an affine open cover. Of course, two divisors are equal if on an affine open cover they induce the same divisors, and so (a) immediately (and I think necessarily) reduces to a local statement. This is precisely your attack for (b), but really it is an approach for (a) from which (b) will immediately follow.

---

Edit: Here is the argument. Choose $U \subset X$ an affine open subscheme such that $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ is trivial and a trivialization $\varphi : \mathcal{O}_U \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(D)|_U$. Then $\mathcal{O}_X(D)|_U$ is generated (as an $\mathcal{O}_U$-module) by $\tau := \varphi(1)$.

Now $1$ is a rational section of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)|_U$ and our trivialization sends $1$ to the rational section $\tau^{-1}$ of $\mathcal{O}_U$. Of course one has that $\mathrm{div}(\tau) + D|_U \geq 0$ and as you mention in the question, we wish to show in fact that $\mathrm{div}_{\mathcal{O}_U}(\tau) = -D|_U$. From this we will get $\mathrm{div}_{\mathcal{O}_X(D)|_U}(1) = \mathrm{div}_{\mathcal{O}_U}(\tau^{-1}) = D|_U$.

So to finish the argument, we must show that $\mathrm{div}_{\mathcal{O}_U}(\tau)+D|_U = 0$. With $\mathrm{div}_{\mathcal{O}_U}(\tau)+D|_U \geq 0$, assume to the contrary that the principal divisor $W$ of $U$ is in the support of $\mathrm{div}_{\mathcal{O}_U}(\tau)+D|_U$. Note that on the affine scheme $U$, there exists a rational section $f$ with a simple pole along $W$. Let $P_1, \dots, P_n$ be the other poles of $f$, noting that this number must be finite ($X$ is Noetherian). Then we can consider a basic affine open subscheme of $U - \cup P_i$ which meets $W$ given by $V = D(g)$ for some regular function $g$ on $U$. Now $\tau|_V$ generates the $\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_V)$-module $\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_V(D|_V))$. Since $f|_V$ has a pole along $Z|_V$, $f|_V$ is not a regular function on $V$ but $\mathrm{div}_{\mathcal{O}_V}(f|_V \cdot \tau|_V)+D|_V \geq 0$. This contradicts the fact that $\tau|_V$ generates $\mathcal{O}_V(D|_V)$, finishing the argument.

---

One additional question that I think is important here: why does this argument *not* prove that $D$ is (globally) principal?

Comment: I can see how (a) is a local problem, but my approach to (a) requires that D is locally principal, and I'm missing how to do (a) without knowing this. Otherwise, for example, it is conceivable that the obvious inclusion $\mathcal{O}_X(D')\hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(D)$ is an isomorphism for some $D'<D$, and I would want to rule that out.

Comment: @Dtseng: I've edited to make the argument more clear. At no point do I need $D$ is locally principal and I am really doing the same thing you are.

Comment: Thanks! (upvote) Do you know if it is possible to show that a height 1 prime of a ring (with some assumptions) isn't contained in the union of the other height 1 primes? In our case, I think we can assume the ring is Noetherian, local, normal, and integral. If so, I will accept an answer so that this question is closed.

Comment: @Dtseng: This is in fact true for any ring. The proof is above.

Comment: I thought of using the prime avoidance lemma, but the issue is that there might be infinitely many height 1 primes. Does your proof still work in this case?

The prime avoidance lemma would allow me to construct a rational function that has a pole at $P$ and avoids poles at finitely many other height 1 primes, but I didn't think this was enough.

Comment: Okay, I think this works, but tell me if you find a problem. I tried the same thing, but, for some reason, I kept thinking of fixing $x\in U$ and trying to force $U\backslash \cup{P_i}$ to contain $x$ (resulting in the question involving height 1 primes in a ring above), which caused me to get stuck for hours. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Certainly, glad I could help. Everything looks good.

Comment: What is "the principal divisor W of U"? What does "having a pole along W" mean?

Comment: @JohnnyApple: the argument should say "a principal divisor" rather than "the". The assumption leading to this phrase implies there exists (at least) one.

Comment: And what did you mean by a pole "along W"?